# Create a recently added playlist?

Tags: itunes, macos, playlist, smart-playlist

Is it possible to have a "Recently Added" as a Playlist on iTunes ? For example, I would like the recent 20-50 songs to be automatically added and renewed in that playlist.

Comment: There should already be such a playlist defined by default (unless you deleted it)

Comment: @patrix Might have deleted it because I don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally there is a default smart playlist with recently added items. If there is no such playlist you can easily recreate one with the following steps:

- Creata a new smart playlist <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
- name it “recently added“
- select match all rules
- select date added is in the last 2 weeks
- select media kind is not podcast
- limit the result to 50 items

This should be it. Of course you can adjust the playlist to your likings (e.g. not last 2 weeks but last two month).

Comment: Also make sure that “live updating” is checked.